# how to reduce time to check conditions in loop or if-else statement

Tags: android, performance, flutter, dart

Flutter and Dart.
Hey there, I am trying to generate unique random numbers in flutter application. Where I am generating 4 random integers which are the answer options for addition of two random integers. Basically I am generating random addition question. lets say 4 + 5. and I am Giving user 4 options like 2 ,4, 20, 9. I am trying to make options unique and once generated then set it to the Text() widget. **But my expression is taking so much time to generate the result that is more than 5 seconds or sometimes 15 to 20. is there any way that I can quickly generate 4 random unique integers? because it is just a 30 second game. and I want to generate answers for next question as soon as user pressed the answer for current question**

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  GenerateQuestion g = new GenerateQuestion();
  g.generateNum();
}

class GenerateQuestion {
  var num1, num2, num3, num4;

  Random random = new Random();
  void generateNum() {
    num1 = random.nextInt(20);
    num2 = random.nextInt(20);
    num3 = random.nextInt(20);
    num4 = random.nextInt(20);
    bool flag = true;
    while (flag == true) {
      if (num1 != num2 && num1 != num3) {
        if (num1 != num4 && num2 != num3) {
          if (num2 != num4 && num3 != num4) {
            print(num1);
            print(num2);
            print(num3);
            print(num4);
            flag = false;
          }
        }
      } //if condition ends here

      else {
        num1 = random.nextInt(20);
        num2 = random.nextInt(20);
        num3 = random.nextInt(20);
        num4 = random.nextInt(20);
        flag = true;
      } // else part ends here
    } // while ends here
  } // generateNum() method ends here
}
```

And one more thing. This is just a separate code that I was trying in Dartpad. therefore it has not containing widgets. I am calling the function onPressed of button. but for the first time when Application starts it is showing me values **null**. yes as function not called it should show null. but How can I also call it before loading the widget and then start working as onPressed?

Comment: Use a set data structure and push random numbers to it until the length is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Illegal Argument you can use a set which will look like this:

```dart
class GenerateQuestionSet {
  var num1, num2, num3, num4;

  final random = Random();

  void generateNum() {
    final numbers = <int>{};
    while (numbers.length < 4) {
      numbers.add(random.nextInt(20));
    }
    final nums = numbers.toList();
    num1 = nums[0];
    num2 = nums[1];
    num3 = nums[2];
    num4 = nums[3];
  }
}
```

Another solution would be to not regenerate all the numbers when there is a duplicate number:

```dart
class GenerateQuestionWhile {
  var num1, num2, num3, num4;

  Random random = Random();
  void generateNum() {
    num1 = random.nextInt(20);
    do {
      num2 = random.nextInt(20);
    } while(num2 == num1);
    do {
      num3 = random.nextInt(20);
    } while(num3 == num2 || num3 == num1);
    do {
      num4 = random.nextInt(20);
    } while(num4 == num3 || num4 == num2 || num4 == num1);
  }
}
```